# Doxygen: Each line in code listings starts with an asterisk (*)

Tags: doxygen, code-formatting

I am using doxygen to create a HTML documentation for a C++ library.

Right now I have the problem that code listings created with `\code ... \endcode` produce listings where each line starts with an asterisk.

Example:

```
Have a look at the following code sample:
\code
int a = 5;
int b = func(a);
\endcode
```

Output:

> ```
> Have a look at the following code sample:
> * int a = 5;
> * int b = func(a);
> ```

I cannot explain this behaviour -- especially because I use `///` instead of `/**` to mark lines as doxygen documentation. The issue happens for both formattings though.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?
(I am using doxygen 1.8.5)

Comment: The following version (doxygen 1.8.5 worked for me):
/**
\code
int a = 5;
int b = func(a);
\endcode
*/
I hope you used /// and not \\\ but this as a side note.

Comment: Of course I used /// (fixed). I do have the feeling the mistake must be somewhere else and doxygen's parsing is screwed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed an unfortunate regression in 1.8.5.

I've just pushed a fix to GitHub. Please let me know if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, it seems fixed. I checked it only briefly but the issue seems gone. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed seems to be a bug in 1.8.5. I downloaded it today from doxygen.nl to update documentation of an existing project which built fine with previous version, now exhibits this behavior. Didn't have a nerve to build it from source so I downgraded to 1.8.4 which works fine. Any idea when the fixed 1.8.5 will be available for download as binary?

Comment: A new version can be expected at the end of the year.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug. [Bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=707567).
Also [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571561) could be related.

I managed to get a workaround by changing the following snippet

```
/// Have a look at the following code sample:
/// \code
/// int a = 5;
/// int b = func(a);
/// \endcode
```

to the following (***note that there are only two slashes***):

```
/// Have a look at the following code sample:
// \code   
// int a = 5;
// int b = func(a);
/// \endcode
```

I am not happy with this because it requires to re-layout all comments and the formatting feels very much unnatural.